# Is it possible to unrequire a module in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browserify, require

I  am using Browserify to require a JS file, like this `require('./typescript/build/crossing-puzzle-setup'` . However, considering there will be many different types of puzzles, I was wondering, is it possible to "unrequire" a module if I no longer need it?

Comment: What's the consequences of loading all of the modules? Modern browsers use a ridiculous amount of memory under normal circumstances so unless you're importing tens of megabytes of JavaScript code this is unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes little sense to unload a module, as the code only takes a very small amount of RAM, and no it is not possible to unload it as the engine cannot predict that `require("some module")` doesnt get called again, so it cannot unload the stored data of that module.

Comment: If there's no references to that any more why wouldn't it get GC'd?

Comment: @tadman I can't speak to browserify, but the Node implementation caches all `require()` returns.

Comment: @Brad That's a good point about Node.js but I'm not sure how this plays out with the newer module-aware browsers.

Comment: @tadman If they're using Browserify, it's going to be using the Browserify loader, yeah?

Comment: @tadman how can you predict that `require("puzzle")` doesnt get called again? Because if that happens, node has to return exactly the same exported things

Comment: @JonasW. That is the expected behaviour, in which case you'd want consistent results. Probably means that the answer to this question is "No".

Answer (score 1):

If you really are loading so much code that you need to force the browser to unload it, you could force the page to refresh and then load the previous state of the page. However, the user will see the browser’s “page loading” indicators during the refresh.

```
function startReload() {
  // Save all the state you need into a string. An example object:
  const importantAppState = {currentPuzzle: 'level1', username: 'roy'};
  localStorage.setItem('stateBeforeReload', JSON.stringify(importantAppState));

  window.location.reload();
}

// Run this function whenever your page loads:
function onLoad() {
  const previousState = localStorage.setItem('stateBeforeReload');
  if (previousState !== null) {
    // you should re-initialize your app from the state here,
    // dynamically calling `require` on only the files you need

    localStorage.removeItem('stateBeforeReload');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for those looking for a nodeJS solution:

```
require('../myLib');
delete require.cache[require.resolve('../myLib')];
```

Not sure if the above clear 100% memory linked to the module. For that, a secure way seem to be using this node module: [node-disrequire](https://github.com/andrasq/node-disrequire)